# In Bash, get name of array being looped through when looping through multiple arrays?

Tags: bash

I have two arrays of different length, and am passing both arrays into a while loop.  Within the while loop, I need access to the name of the array.  I can write this as a function, but am curious if there is a way to do it without.

```
arr1=( "a" "b" "c" )
arr2=( "d" "e" "f" "g" )
for str in ${arr1[@]} ${arr2[@]}; do
  echo $str
  echo ${NAME_OF_ARRAY}
done
```

with the expected result:

```
a
arr1
b
arr1
c
arr1
d
arr2
e
arr2
f
arr2
g
arr2
```

Is there a way of extracting the name of the array like this from within a for loop?

Comment: The fact that the words you iterate over originally came from an array expansion is lost, so no. Any solution would be based on workarounds like prefixing the word with the array name or adding canary words.

Comment: BTW, not quoting `"${arr1[@]}"` makes your quotes elsewhere useless -- try testing with `arr1=( "first element" "second element" )` to catch such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Instead, with bash 4.3 or newer, loop over the array names, using a namevar to alias each in turn.

```
arr1=( "a" "b" "c" )
arr2=( "d" "e" "f" "g" )

for arr_name in arr1 arr2; do      # assign each array name to arr_name in turn
  declare -n arr_cur=$arr_name     # make arr_cur an alias for arr_name
  for str in "${arr_cur[@]}"; do   # iterate over "${arr_cur[@]}"
     echo "${arr_name} - ${str}"
  done
  unset -n arr_cur                 # revert that assignment
done
```

...[properly emits](https://ideone.com/XtCBjs):

```
arr1 - a
arr1 - b
arr1 - c
arr2 - d
arr2 - e
arr2 - f
arr2 - g
```

Comment: In older versions of bash, you can use indirect expansion instead, with `arr_cur=${arr_name}[@]` and `for str in "${!arr_cur}"; do`.

Comment: That's perfect for what I'm doing.  Thanks!